# String intern for synchronisation

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, synchronization, thread-safety

```
public final static HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();//global variable

//this is a post method

    String forSync = null;

//somewhere here init forSync
...

        if(forSync != null){
            Object obj = null;
            synchronized(map){
                obj = map.get(forSync);//can be not empty
                if(obj == null){
                    obj  = new Object();
                    map.put(forSync.intern(), obj );
                }
            }
        synchronized(obj){
//sync block
}
```

String don't synchronize properly . Will this work or I should change

```
        obj = map.get(forSync);
        obj = map.get(forSync.intern());
```

could you please explain what will be difference if I get with and with ought .intern() . I tried and the result was the same , 
It seems to me that I don't understand properly how intern works.

Comment: What do you mean by "String don't synchronize properly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as synchronization and thread-safety are concerned, `intern()` makes no difference. `Map` uses the string's hashcode to look up values and this value doesn't change (`String` is an immutable or a "value type"). It's always safe to use as key. `synchronized` on the `map` will make sure that the internal data structure of the map can't be corrupted by parallel access. It has no effect on the String itself.

`String.intern()` sometimes makes a difference if you have many strings with the same value. In that case, you can use the pool to save some memory. Many here means 100'000+. It doesn't make sense to use this for a few thousand strings; Java is optimized to death in this area. Just putting values into the pool often simply bloats the pool without much benefit.

Comment: Might also mention that .equals() is used in addition to the hashCode. One plausible explanation for the OP wanting to use .intern() on the key is if he assumes a key comparison is done using the == operator, and not e.g. .equals()